# What is "Letter Distribution" and what is "Word Distribution" in NLP dataset while preforming Exploratory data analysis(EDA)

Tags: python, database, nlp, data-science, data-analysis

Guys im new to data analyst, Im trying to improve my skills so I toke a dataset from kaggle. [these are task of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdQuW.jpg)
I'm stuck on task 3 and 4 of EDA. anyone help me regarding this and how I can perform it.
[Note: This is not any project. I just want to improve my skills for a job]

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Off-site links and [images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable, and is likely a violation of your school's academic honesty policies.
If you do not understand the assignment, your usual remedy is to ask the instructor.

Answer (score 1):

They want you to count the # (instances) of each word or letter in the dataset.

This is part of the EDA, however, so I believe you don't strictly need to do it, it is just potentially helpful for identifying further avenues for analysis.

Comment: can you tell me how to perform it and trying from 2 days but i cant find, i can share my dataset

Comment: As the other user mentioned, please make some progress and make a more specific question, with some code highlighting exactly what you're stuck on.